# D-Link DIR-600L Wireless N150 D Link Cloud Router do not connect to internet

Tags: router, internet

I have recently purchased Dlink 600L router, but my router do not connect to internet. Whenever I click on connect, the connection can not be established. Log is generated as something like

```
WAN tried establishing connection
Sending PDA packets
```

But when I connect ethernet cable directly to PC, I am able to connect and also I have opened MAC from ISP.

Connection type is PPPOE.

Comment: Have you configured the router to use PPPOE per the configuration provided by your ISP?  It honestly sounds like, if thats the case, you will need your contact your ISP to whitelist your router's MAC address.

Comment: @Ramhound I have whitelist my MAC address but even then it's not working. I there any specific error log is generated to find exception.

Comment: @Ramhound I am sure that MAC is whitelisted but if suppose that is not the case the MAC Clone should work but even that is not working in my case.

Comment: I would contact your ISP so they can help you diagnose the problem with you.   Because if the PPPOE configuration is correct, and the device is whitelisted, then it should work.

Comment: @Ramhound the most funniest thing is that my ISP don't know why it is not connecting.

Comment: @Ramhound why MAC clone is also not working if in case MAC address is not whitelisted.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for me to even speculate on the reason your unable to clone your PC's MAC address.

Comment: @Ramhound what Kind of information shall I provide.